# Add array items to Gutenberg SelectControl

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to grab all headings from a page in WordPress dashboard and add them to a Gutenberg `SelectControl` component that can be selected as an option. I'm able to grab the headings and spread them into an array from a NodeList, but having trouble getting the array options values into the `SelectControl`. This is what I have so far:

```
let headers = setTimeout(() => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-heading')].map(item => item.innerText);
}, 1000);

<SelectControl
    label="Header"
    value={headers}
    options={headers}
    onChange={setJumpHeader}
/>
```

How can I get the array elements from `headers` into the options of the `SelectControl`?

Answer (score 0):

So the key is to loop over the array of items and add them to options elements:

```
let headers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-heading')].map(item => item.innerText);
    const select = document.getElementById('selectheader');
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                let opt = headers[i];
                let el = document.createElement('option');
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }
        }, 1000);
```